# PHP: Creating some sort of common pool of variables from where php code can pick up variables

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, phpmyadmin

I believe in PHP, whenever a user sends a request to backend PHP page, there is a one-to-one communication started, that is, a new instance of that page is created and executed as per the request of user.

My question, if each time a new instance is created, I want to create a PHP script, which is shared among all instances,

For ex: I want to store few hundred random numbers in that script (lets name it as pool.php - A static pool), and each time a request to Back end page ( lets say BE.php ) is made, BE.php requests pool.php to return a unique variable each time, and once all variables are used, I will put a logic in pool.php to create new set of variables

If my question is not clear, pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is a good candidate for this.

It is a key/value store that persists despite PHP coming and going.  You can write values from one PHP script and read them from another.  This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but can be used for the same purpose, and is much easier to deal with than sockets connecting to other PHP scripts.

http://memcached.org/

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try, and will revert, until then what abt the performance, will memcached will add an overhead?

Comment: @Tarun, Yes, but far less than dealing with a daemonized PHP script.  Memcached is built to be extremely fast.

Comment: that is great, but right now I am cursing my shared hosting provider, It seems they dont have memcached enabled, Is there any alternative or workaround

Comment: The easiest/best solution is to get a better hosting provider.

Comment: I found one more solution using APC, which lucily my hosting provider supports, I hope it doesnt cost me much CPU :)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with MySQL and locking the table in question. Keep this pool of variables in a separate table, then use SQL table-level lock to hold-off other requests until current request is finished, by using:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK( 'my_lock', 10 ) AS success
```

Make sure to check that the query returns 1, which means you now have a lock. If it doesn't, your query timed out waiting for the lock.

Then perform your ordinary query, like checking if a non-occupied variable exists. If so, occupy it by updating it or whatever.

Then you release the lock, using:

```
DO RELEASE_LOCK( 'my_lock' )
```

The number 10 is the timeout that each request will wait before failing.

Comment: I am not looking for storing the variables in a table, that will be a huge performance overhead, Imagine, If I have to use these variables as Unique IDentifier for each comment user post, so I will have to make a query to table just to get an ID for a post :(

Comment: It might solve the issue in some other scenario, but not on mine

Answer (score 1):

**Tarun**, you do know that databases have something called `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields that can be used as `primary keys` for your user comments. And every time you add a new comment, that field gets incremented by the DB server and you get a `unique ID` on every new entry without breaking a sweat?

The only viable way for your need is using a database and some kind of `Mutex` or **MySQL**'s internal `Mutex` like **John Severinson** said if the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field will not suffice.

**PS**: **Performance overhead**... when talking about PHP scripting is kind of a non-issue. If you need performance, write your sites in C/C++. You are talking about milliseconds *(0.001 seconds)* or less. If that will impact your performance, you need to revisit your project/logic.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is not going to solve the problem, Please try to read the ques properly. By the way APC is going to solve my problem

Comment: And moreover if you could have read my post carefully, You see John is mentioning about request getting failed, If i need that ID from pool, as a id for a html tag, than i dont have option of failed request and it will be defn slow too. APC is much faster

Comment: @Tarun Learn to use a DB first! To create AUTOINCREMENT field values, the DB handles sync internally (that's how they power mega-sites). So you'll always have different values with as many sync requests. The Mutex was only to give you comfort. o.O ... Mmmkay.

Comment: of all the things, you should learn to read the question and comments properly. Why you are so confident that your soln will solve my problem? Huh. I wanted that ID before I insert the values in the DB, APC is much better soln, Let me say that again, My query has been answered already, and the soln works, I dont want to use AUTO_INCREMENT, Have a good day

Comment: @Tarun, I don't care about your vote. I just tried to help. (PS: Almost 10 years of doing this tells me this is the solution.) Cheers! - I'm out of this topic.

Comment: :), let me quote it again APC is working for me, and AUTOINCREMENT doesnt works in my scenario. I do belive it might have worked in your scenario. (PS: It doesnt matter whether you care or not :) )